# Arranging one image on top of another in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm making a solitaire game in HTML/CSS/JavaScript and I have it so that when you click a card and then another it moves the first card to the same position as the second with the y value shifter 20px. The problem is when I move the first card(king) to the second card(queen) the king is beneath the queen. I would like to make it so that whenever you move a card, that card is put on top.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
var x1 = '';
var x2 = '';
var y1 = '';
var y2 = '';
var img1 = '';

function move(id) {
  var id = document.getElementById(id);
  Pr('0');
  if (img1 == '') {
    Pr('1');
    img1 = id;
    Pr(img1);
    var box1 = id.getBoundingClientRect();
    x1 = box1.left + box1.width * 0.5;
    y1 = box1.top + box1.height * 0.5;
  } else if (img1 != '') {
    Pr('2');
    img2 = id;
    Pr(img2);
    var box2 = id.getBoundingClientRect();
    x2 = box2.left;
    y2 = box2.top + 20;
    img1.style.cssText = 'left:' + x2 + 'px;top:' + y2 + 'px;';

  };

  Pr('x1 = ' + x1 + ' | y1 = ' + y1 + ' | x2 = ' + x2 + ' | y2 = ' + y2);
};



//Making 'console.print(...)' quicker to type

function Pr(str) {
  console.log(str)
};
```

```css
.card {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div style='position:relative;'>

  <img class='card' style='left:150px;' id='KD' onclick='move("KD")' src='Cards/Diamonds/K.png'>

  <img class='card' id='QD' src="Cards/Diamonds/Q.png" onclick='move("QD")' style=''>
</div>
```

[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IylkF.png)

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95RWJ.png)

[Here's the link to the site](https://solitaire-game.sachro.repl.co/)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
var t = 0;
var img1 = '';
var img2 = '';
function move(id){
  if (t==0){
    img1 = document.getElementById(id);
    id1 = id;
    t=1;
  }else if (t==1){
    t=0; 
    id2 = id;
    img2 = document.getElementById(id);
    var rect = img1.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rect2 = img2.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x1 = rect.left + rect.width * 0.5;
    var y1 = rect.top + rect.height * 0.5;
    var x2 = rect2.left;
    var y2 = rect2.top + 20;
    img1.style.cssText = 'z-index:2;left:'+x2+'px;top:'+y2+'px;';
  }; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `z-index` to the image (`z-index: 1` should suffice), and each additionally added image needs to get a value higher than the previous one (using some "+1" logic for the value in the script).